# request()->file() only contains first file

Tags: php, laravel, file

Say I have these inputs for a dynamic slideshow generator:

```
<input type="text" name="slides[0][heading]" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="slides[0][background_image]" class="form-control">

<input type="text" name="slides[1][heading]" class="form-control">
<input type="file" name="slides[1][background_image]" class="form-control">
```

I'm trying to retrieve all of the uploaded files. However, `request()->file()` only gives me the first file uploaded:

```
foreach (request()->file() as $file)
{
    print_r($file);
    // file upload logic here
}
```

This only shows me one file. How do I get all of them?

Comment: You're doing a `dd` inside the `foreach`, so it's normal you only see the first file. Shouldn't you `dd(request()->file());` instead?

Comment: You are _literally_ only dumping the first file and then exiting the script.

Comment: It doesn't matter. A `print_r` also only shows 1 file. I've updated the OP.

Comment: Shouldn't your loop be `foreach($request->file("slides") AS $file){ ... }`?

Comment: No because the key name has to be completely dynamic so that this remains modular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I could figure it out was by changing the names to use dash notations e.g. `slides-0-heading` and then do an `str_replace('-', '.', $name)` and use `array_set` in the controller.